# maven how to re-download jar while change the repository url

Tags: maven

Once I change the repository url and I want to test how this center downloading jars (in local repo I have downloaded jars and I want to delete those jars and restart download).

Does any maven plugin or command support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

See [Purging local repository dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html)